# Google Console APK Upload - New App fails

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-console, google-console-developer

Recently trying to create a new App and upload a brand new APK with self signed certificate (Not Google App Signing) Results in the following error

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a restricted certificate. You need to upload an APK or Android App Bundle signed with your own certificate.

I don't believe this error is entirely correct as I do sign the certificate myself locally, this seems like a recent change to our on boarding process and opt-in is now default for google app signing but our infrastructure doesn't have the right pipeline for this yet.

Is there any other things to verify and test, as I see  the keystone file is still there and there's no build errors when it's being signed. Also this is a brand **NEW** application I don't understand why this error would occur for the initial upload since there's no other keys to check against.

I've searched the net but most issues appear to be happening in 2018 and this is more of a recent change that started to occur for us.

EDIT: This is using Cordova build tools not through Android Studio.

[image: con]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a full answer as to **Why** it was failing, however right after the build for `cordova build android --release` that APK will upload. But If I use that APK in an emulator to test something first that APK is no longer valid to upload and I get the error pasted above.

basically in our pipeline I had to create a copy of the APK right before creating screenshots and then use the copied APK to upload onto google console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these trouble shoot steps and see if that will solve your issue:

Clear everything in the **Release** folder, present in `app->build->outputs->apk->release.`

Generate new signed apk which will get created in the same above mentioned directory.

Make sure you are bumping the version code.

Comment: I should have specified, this is part of our build server that utilizes Cordova. I did try to follow up and see if there's something with the keystore and perhaps some other permissions that Android Studio / Gradle might need but to no avail.